# How to find all towns/cities within a driving distance of a particular city?

Tags: maps, gis, bing-maps, bing

I am looking for an API to return a list of cities, given the current city (may be coordinates) and some specified driving distance. If driving distance is unfeasible, the list of cities within a radius is also acceptable. Any suggestions on what I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure why you would do something like that, but you have multiple ways to do so.

- **Easy way:**

You need to get an area and create multiple location around your point (or your given city that you would geocode) and then you can use services that give you a multiple reverse geocoding feature like Here Platform does for example. In this way, you would get multiple cities and then you could filter the duplicated entries.

See: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/request-first-multi-reverse-geocode.html

- **Complicated way but way more powerful:**

Using the Here Platform, you can retrieve Drivetime area (also called isochronous) so based on a location and a duration, you can retrieve the geometry based on the selected transport mode.

See: http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-routing/topics/resource-calculate-isoline.html#resource-calculate-isoline

Based on this geometry, you can create point as explained before or you can use your own database to query on which would contain city geometries for example.

Hope this helps, I know it's only explained and not coded (no code samples here), but it works for sure. I'll try to put more concrete cases but I'm sorry not now.